# How to Create multiple Rows at once?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5.2

How do I create multiple rows on my table at once?
I want to be able to add non-existent rows, and edit/update existing rows whenever I press submit.

To test this I only created 2 fields in the database, and cannot seem to add more than one row.

Value of numofbuilding = 5.
Only one row is inserted.

Tried:

```
public ActionResult CreateBuildings(Guid pi, int? numofbuilding)
{
    OnboardModel model = new OnboardModel();
    List<onboard_BuildingInfo> coms = new List<onboard_BuildingInfo>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= (numofbuilding+1); i++)
    { 
        onboard_BuildingInfo f = new onboard_BuildingInfo
        {
            projectID = pi,
            building_ID = i
        };
        coms.Add(f);
    }
    context.onboard_BuildingInfos.InsertAllOnSubmit(coms);
    context.SubmitChanges();
    return View(model);
}
```

and tried:

```
public ActionResult CreateBuildings(Guid pi, int? numofbuilding)
{
    OnboardModel model = new OnboardModel();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numofbuilding; i++)
    { 
        onboard_BuildingInfo coms = new onboard_BuildingInfo
        {
            projectID = pi,
            building_ID = i
        };
        context.onboard_BuildingInfos.InsertOnSubmit(coms);
        context.SubmitChanges();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

BuildingInfo-Table

```
Create Table onboard_BuildingInfo (
        projectID                       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT        NEWID() ,
        building_ID                     int                 NULL ,  
        city_building                   varchar(500)        NULL ,
        numberofcommon                  INT                 NULL 
        PRIMARY KEY (projectID)
     )
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Do you get an error? Is only one row inserted? What is the value of your variable called numofbuilding? Is it 2 per chance.... haha

Comment: @Milney value of numofbuilding is 5. and yes,only one row is inserted.

Comment: We would need to see the code for your repository.

Comment: What info exactly do you need to see @ChrisPratt - I don't understand, sorry. I believe the problem is because projectID is a GUID unique primary key. So only allowing one version to exist.

Comment: @ChrisPratt that's not the issue. I made that field a variable, and still was unable to create multiple rows... What info in my repo do you need to see? I don't know what that means.

Comment: What are the keys/indexes on that table? I'm wondering if the GUID projectID column is the Primary Key or just set up with a unique constraint. Could you please post the DDL (CREATE TABLE....) statement for that table?

Comment: @ridecar2 it'll work if it's not a primary key? it is, I edited above.

Comment: You are not using LinQ anywhere. Looks like Entity Framework. Please retag accordingly, I'll remove the LinQ tag.

Comment: @nvoigt I am not using Entity Framework, the database is setup with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Ok, added the correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `projectID` not a primary key, or have a composite key on `projectID` and `building_ID`. Primary keys must be unique therefore you cannot have duplicate items in the `projectID` column. A composite key would mean that the combination of (`projectID` * `building_ID`) must be unique therefore you may have duplicates in either column, but not both.